# Ruby Joins and Select but can't see all that is selected, why?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, select, join

I have this code...

```
User.find :all, 
          :select => "users.id, departments.name, users.username, response_sets.id AS 'response_set_id', response_sets.survey_id, COUNT(responses.id) AS 'answers', response_sets.completed_at", 
          :joins => "LEFT JOIN departments ON users.department_id = departments.id LEFT JOIN versions ON departments.version_id = versions.id LEFT JOIN response_sets ON users.id = response_sets.user_id AND versions.survey_id = response_sets.survey_id LEFT JOIN responses ON response_sets.id = responses.response_set_id AND responses.answer_id IS NOT NULL", 
          :conditions => {:id => 4}, 
          :group => "users.id"
```

And all it's returning is this `[#<User id: 4, username: "3333">]` should there be more? because of my `:select`?? should I have use `:include` instead of `:joins`..still learning..newbie here! xP

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There actually is more in all the instances but what you see is the result of a call to the method `inspect` and that will only show the content of the actual columns from the User model. But if you try to call the other values returned by your statement you should be able to see the result. For example:

```
@users.first.response_set_id # => will return the value from response_sets.id
@users.first.answers         # => will return the value from COUNT(responses.id)
```

Comment: check if that doesn't do additional queries to database

Comment: It does not. Custom selects stores all returned columns in the instance.

Answer (score 0):

ActiveRecord in Rails gives you kind of ORM. This means that you working with object. So when you use `include` to join other table(s) - it's fields will not appear in result table. To get them you need to call `parent_table.joined_table.your_field` on result query. With `join` - field will be available. So if you joined some tables it will be better to explicitly call to them and get their columns.
BTW read difference between `join` and `include`: [find method](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Base/find/class)

Answer (score 0):

Example

```
...select("orders.*, cities.name AS city_name, countries.name AS country_name, customers.account_id as customer_acc").
      joins("LEFT JOIN customers ON customers.id = orders.customer_id")....
```

and then in view I can access to additional data with []

```
<td><%= order[:country_name] %></td>
<td><%= order[:city_name] %></td>
```